# WCF C# webservice to accept file in XML Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, attachment

I am attempting to recieve a SOAP post signal with WCF that has the files attached and declared in an XML attribute as such:

```
<ATTACHMENTS>
  <ATTACHMENT href="cid:338131408997"/>
</ATTACHMENTS>
```

How should i go about capturing this sort of request in WCF? I have tried with the XmlSerializerFormat and was able to make the same format but end up with

```
FormatException on the ':' character.
```

The sender is unwilling to make any changes. I have tried searching the web extensivley but i cannot seem to find a way to accept this in C# WCF.

Does anyone know how to accept these sort of messages with WCF .NET framework? I would like to accept these without setting up another API if possible.

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to parse a request manually, it seems to be a valid XML.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IContract
{
    [OperationContract, WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "UploadAttachments")]
    void UploadAttachments(Stream messageContent);
}
public class Service : IContract
{
    public void UploadAttachments(Stream messageContent)
    {
        var xml = XElement.Load(messageContent);
        var hrefs = xml
            .Elements("ATTACHMENT")
            .Select(attachmentElement => attachmentElement.Attribute("href").Value);
        foreach (var href in hrefs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(href);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can actually get into the method now! Which is great.